# ¿De dónde proviene el acento usado en los doblajes de la voz de campesinos estadounidenses?

Tags: diferencias-regionales, dialectos, hispanoamérica, estados-unidos

Es recurrente escuchar en series o películas estadounidenses que han sido dobladas al español latino el [siguiente acento](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=G6jrPUhg9BA) (desconozco si en doblaje de España lo usen también).

Esto no es algo nuevo, porque tengo recuerdos incluso de niño haber escuchado en series como `Los Dukes de Hazzard` una voz en off que hablaba con ese acento, o como [en estas caricaturas](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=KpL4SQv4-4Q) que aportan en los comentarios. Sin embargo no recuerdo alguna vez haber escuchado a alguien que **efectivamente** hable con tal acento, al menos en Chile (país donde vivo) no conozco ninguna zona que la gente hable así y podría decir lo mismo de países aledaños como Argentina, Perú, Bolivia o incluso mas al norte como Ecuador o Colombia.

Ahora, sin ninguna base de peso que las sustente, estas son mis suposiciones de donde proviene el acento:

- Existen zonas rurales en México donde la gente hable así, después de todo en los inicios de las series dobladas con acento latino neutro, México fue responsable del doblaje de gran parte de éstas, sin embargo el ejemplo del video es doblado en [Colombia y Venezuela](http://es.doblaje.wikia.com/wiki/Duck_Dynasty), por tanto como ya ha quedado en el subconsciente colectivo que hablan así, se ha mantenido independiente de donde se doble.
- Los estadounidenses campesinos que hablen español terminan hablando con ese acento, aunque tampoco nunca he escuchado un estadounidenses que hable Español con dicho acento.
- Es un acento inexistente que fue creado al tratar de adaptar el acento campesino estadounidense a como sonaría si se hablase en español.

Entonces ¿alguien conoce de dónde proviene este acento?

Comment: Definitivamente no es el acento de un anglohablante nativo sureño en el español (soy de dicha zona, aunque mi acento mío es definitivamente madrileño). La mujer me suena caribeña, el hombre, ni idea.

Comment: En [esta web](http://es.doblaje.wikia.com/wiki/Duck_Dynasty) puedes encontrar los dobladores a español para la serie Duck Dynasty, transmitida en Latinoamérica por el canal A&E. No me queda claro a qué personaje te refieres (el link cambia de episodio cada vez que pincho), pero si es uno de los personajes principales en esa web puedes ver quién es el doblador y siguiendo el enlace de cada nombre, aprender un poco de su biografía (donde nacieron/crecieron/estudiaron...) que puede dar más pistas para localizar el acento. Por lo menos puede servir como base a una nueva búsqueda.

Comment: Recuerdo ese acento de escucharlo en el doblaje de _Los osos montañeses_ (https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=KpL4SQv4-4Q) (donde es aún más pronunciado), me hacía y me hace mucha gracia. No tengo manera de verificarlo, así que sería bueno que alguien nos desasne, pero tenía la idea de que es un acento norteño exagerado adrede.

Comment: @Diego de hecho el link que me envías lo incluí originalmente en la pregunta, sin embargo no me dio mayores pistas

Comment: @JMVanPelt si, hay varios dibujos antiguos de Looney Tunes/ Hanna Barbera en los que usaban ese acento, al menos recuerdo de niño que era bastante común.

Comment: No son los acentos que son llamativos. Es la **intonación**.  Y son los actores que se lo inventan. Están haciendo un calco de la intonación del inglés con un acento latino americano no marcado (o sea,  no se identica ningún pais).

Answer (score 3):

Conozco la mayoría de los acentos usados en México y te puedo decir que nadie habla así en el país, mas bien parece ser un acento inventado por las personas de doblaje, que mezcla cosas de los rednecks americanos con un poco (pero MUY poco) de los campesinos mexicanos de algunas zonas de México, nadie en todo el país habla remotamente cercano a eso.

Answer (score 1):

Creo que es una versión absurdamente exagerada del [Cajun English](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cajun_English), uno de los dialectos sureños de Estados Unidos asociado a las zonas pantanosas de Louisiana.

No sé si estos ejemplos sean "reales", pero se nota cierta similitud: [Swamp People](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=r6NteKbbCN0) y la luciérnaga Raymond en [La Princesa y el Sapo](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=k2vOEZEYdIs) de Disney

Comment: Es español, nada que inglés.

Answer (score 1):

Donde vivo muchas personas hablan asi, pues este es el acento tipo del norte de México. Una  gran cantidad de personas lo tienen, especialmente en las zonas serranas.

Algunos ejemplos:

https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=qeyAHQSO9Ug

https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=h_XCfgiMAno

Comment: Si, bueno, claramente la ignorancia me trajo aquí a preguntar, no es necesario recalcar lo obvio. Creo que deberías revisar [answer] para que veas lo que se espera  de una respuesta en esta comunidad, sobretodo lo de [comportamiento esperado](https://spanish.stackexchange.com/help/behavior). Saludos

Comment: De verdad es una lástima, porque tu respuesta verdaderamente responde mi pregunta después de 6 años que la hice, pero la manera en la cual la planteas, es lamentable.

Comment: Disculpa si te ofendi hombre no es para tanto ademas nunca me referi  como ignorante al que hizo la pregunta sino a la bola de respuestas incorrectas que encontre de personas que aseguran algo que es incorrecto.

Comment: Ademas los nortenos somos las personas mas francas que  existen eso dicen todos los que nos conocen pero somos las mas sinceras generosas que vas a conocer te lo aseguro. Los surenos son bastante sentidos nosotros tenenos cero diplomacia pero mucha sinceridad de corazon te lo garantizo al 100 Bueno cuidate que la pases bien en verdad me agrada que encontraras la respuesta a tu pregunta despues de tanto tiempo

Comment: Bueno, he escuchado mucho esta intonación en series mexicanas. PERO, en la pregunta no tienen lo que se llama singsong en inglés. Para mi, los videos aqui y el de arriba no son iguales. El de arriba es como un calco de la intonación americana y aqui el español cantado es otra cosa.